# Amazon S3 plugin uploading to different directory

Tags: assets, plugins, s3, amazon

I was using Amazon S3 with Craft 2 fine, now after updating and installing the plugin I am having issues.

We use a folder inside our bucket as the root Assets location - e.g. /bucket-name//folder

When specifying /folder/ in the subfolder field existing images display. e.g. /bucket-name//folder/image.jpg.

However, on uploading, new images are being sent to /bucket-name/folder/image.jpg - which means they don't display on templates.

If I then specify the folder as //folder/ in the subfolder field, and remove the trailing slash from the base url, images do not get uploaded to the correct place, and existing images do not load on the site, as it thinks I am calling ///folder/image.jpg.

Any suggestions would be great, as I'm going round in circles!

Also no image resizes are working, which I currently assume is due to the folder discrepancy.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, it looked like it was thanks to the blank folder name - moving it all to a new folder which actually has a name seems to have done the trick!